# Deployment of CQRS in a shared Asp.net environment

Tags: cqrs

I'm new to CQRS but I understand the intent behind it. From the few documents that I went through, I did not understand how can I deploy a CQRS application/service in a shared asp.net hosting environment (hosting provided by GoDaddy or DiscountAsp.net). Does the hosting server need to have MSMQ or similar message processing application to have CQRS working? Or it can work via asynchronous communication which is available in MVC4, WCF Service or Asp.net application.

Feedback appreciated as well as any links that talk about the deployment aspect of CQRS in a shared environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the hosting server need to have MSMQ or similar message
>   processing application to have CQRS working?

Generally yes, but it of course depends on your definition of CQRS. Some would for instance consider a single data store architecture only using distinct read and write models as CQRS. In this case there is no need for explicit synchronization of read and write stores. In the the usual sense however, synchronization needs between and read and write is required and is usually implemented with a messaging system of which MSMQ is an instance.

> Does the hosting server need to have MSMQ or similar message
>   processing application to have CQRS working?

Async in ASP.NET MVC is used for processing a single request asynchronously, not for performing background tasks or passing messages between processes and/or nodes such as, say, write and read stores.

Some suggestions:

- Consider hosting the infrastructure required for CQRS on a provider such as Azure, AWS, AppHarbor, iron.io, etc.
- Consider using something like RavenHQ for the data store since RavenDB can effectively support CQRS out of the box. In both this and the previous case you can still use GoDaddy or the like to host the front facing ASP.NET app, if absolutely neccessary.